# In API testing, Status code returns 200 but in response body code returns 201, 500 codes?

Tags: web-api-testing

**Status code : 200**

Actual Response:
{
"code":500,
"error": "error inserting"
}
,
{
"code:201,
"message": "created successfully"
}

Is this a correct response or status code should be same as in response body?

Comment: May you post your code.

Comment: Don't have the code and checked  the API using swagger

Comment: Need to check whether it is a  valid response or status code also reflect the same code returns in actual response

Comment: @Lakshmi The API is using the wrong error codes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here the http method is PUT. So it returns different code in result and actual output??

Answer (score 0):

If some kind of ingress gateway is used, the app can't return 500, otherwise, the ingress gateway will try to retry the request, so the status code is returned in the body.

You can use the custom header for the status code to comply with RESTFul API.